# How is it possible to show a different number of decimals in one column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get a different number of decimals in one column in a pandas dataframe. I have rounded the values in the concerning columns to the right amount of decimals, however, the whole column shows the maximum number of decimals.

For example I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column Name':[1005, 100.5, 10.05, 1.005]})

1005.000
100.500
10.050
1.005
```

Whereas I want it to be like:

```
1005
100.5
10.05
1.005
```

How is this possible?

Comment: if you can prepare an [mcve], it helps make it easier to provide answers.

Comment: You can do what @Andreas says. But I think the dataframe will work faster if you use it as a `dtype='float64'` column because it can make more homogeneous operations

Answer (score 2):

Just set the dtype to `object` so that the integer `1005` remains integer (otherwise all the values are automatically converted to float64):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column Name':[1005, 100.5, 10.05, 1.005]}, dtype='O')

df
Out[33]: 
  Column Name
0        1005
1       100.5
2       10.05
3       1.005
```

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions:

```
df['Column Name'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(\d{4}|.{5})')
```

Note that the capturing group in the pattern is without name, so the resulting
column has name == *0*. If you want this column to have some meaningful name,
use a **named** capturing group instead, e.g.:

```
df['Column Name'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(?P<Number>\d{4}|.{5})')
```